# How to predict the behavior of Autonomous Navigator of ROS?

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

1. I am specifically interested in predicting the next move of autonomous navigator of ROS.
2. What should be the packages, I need to look at. I have gone
   through [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) ?
3. I f I want to modify the behavior of autonomous navigator of ROS; in which direction I should
   proceed.

**Many thanks** for any kind of help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201412/how-to-predict-the-behavior-of-autonomous-navigator-of-ros?/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-01-21**:
what do you mean by "predicting the next move of autonomous navigator" ?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-22**:
By "Predicting the next move"; I want to say how the trajectories have been chosen+constructed+updated? and  how these trajectories can be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for planning and navigation, ROS uses a node called **move_base**. Roughly, it divides the planning problem in two parts, the first creates a complete path from the start to the goal and is called **global planner** and another part creates local trajectories so the robot can follow the global path, and is called **local planner**.
In the way this node is implemented, it allow you to use different local and global planners. By default, the global planner is called **navfn**, which implements Dijkstra's algorithm.
For more info:

[move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base?distro=indigo)

[global_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner?distro=indigo)

[navfn](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn?distro=indigo)

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-23**:
Thanks for the answer.What other dependencies (in terms of packages), I need to check to add my own strategies for trajectory selection in **navfn**?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-01-23**:
for more details, you can check here [Writing A Global Path Planner As Plugin in ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS). If my response answered your question, pleas mark it as correct.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-23**:
I am using ROS fuerte. Will this tutorial page help me as well?

By the way ..thanks again Procópio

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-01-23**:
I̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶s̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶F̶u̶e̶r̶t̶e̶,̶ but I strongly suggest that you update your ROS distro. Currently we are at ROS Indigo, which is 3 versions away from Fuerte (which already reached its End of Life). You are welcome.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-24**:
That tutorial looks alright for Fuerte.